# Wi-FiのRSSIの値をiPhone（iOS8）で取得するAPI

Tags: xcode, ios8

Wi-FiのRSSIの値をiPhone（iOS9）で自動取得するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

AirMacユーティリティのWi-Fiスキャナという機能にて、各アクセスポイントのRSSI値を取得できるので、APIがあると思われます。ご存知の方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。
（APP Storeでの配布は不要ですので、Private APIでも構いません）

参考：[iOS 8: Wireless roaming reference for enterprise customers - Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203068)

Comment: このような情報でお役にたてるか分かりませんが、どうやら Apple80211 というプライベート API があるようです。http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework